# Rails will_paginate custom renderer manual page number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, custom-renderer

Hy
What i want to do is to create a custom renderer for will_paginate which renders first, previous, next and last page and a input field where the user can type in the page number manually. I already have the links for first, last etc. but i stuck at the input field. I could create a form in the view but the input field has to be rendered between the previous and next links.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a separate form (make sure it is a GET). All you
need is the one input element named page. Something as simple as this
should work (not all browsers may like the #). I dropped it into a
site I'm playing with now and it worked. Put it anywhere on your page.
You might have to make something more complicated if you need to
incorporate search terms.

```
<form action="#" method="get">
  Go to page: <input type="text" name="page" value="" size="2"  
maxlength="4" />
  <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes i could to that but as already written, the input field (the form) has to be placed between the previous and the next links and these links are rendered by my custom pagination renderer.